# Representation theory in cryptography/coding theory

Tags: group-theory, coding-theory

How can representation theory be used in cryptography and/or coding theory?

I am studying a MSc in pure mathematics and I am currently working on things related to biset functors, but cryptography and coding theory are some of my interest areas. I know that classical representation theory (complex character theory) can be applied in group codes, but I haven't found anything related to biset functors, Burnside rings or modular representation theory.

Does anyone know if these techniques can be useful in theoretical cryptography or in coding theory?

Comment: does the answer address your question? if not why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In “Alternating Product Ciphers: A Case for Provable Security Comparisons” by J. Pliam https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.4107

some representation theory is used. Here is a snippet of the Proof of Theorem 1

[image]